# "make" error when I want to make libsvm (system : MAC OS X 10.12.6)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, libsvm

when i make under the libsvm/python  folder,terminal show that:

```
make -C .. lib
c++ -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp -c svm.cpp
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make[1]: *** [svm.o] Error 1
make: *** [lib] Error 2
```

so i try to find the mistake,and I think it's the problem of my gcc compile,because I change some files before.

so I started to test it . 
just simply write a     test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

I used the command:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

and

```
./test
```

There were lots of ERROR

```
In file included from tset.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:242:81: error: expected function body after function declarator
FILE    *fopen(const char * __restrict __filename, const char * __restrict __mode) __DARWIN_ALIAS_STARTING(...
                                                                                   ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:244:63: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      fprintf(FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(2, 3);
                                                                  ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:246:56: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      fputs(const char * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS(fputs);
                                                           ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:249:37: error: expected function body after function declarator
                 FILE * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS(freopen);
                                    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:250:62: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      fscanf(FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __scanflike(2, 3);
                                                                 ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:254:107: error: expected function body after function declarator
  ...void * __restrict __ptr, size_t __size, size_t __nitems, FILE * __restrict __stream) __DARWIN_ALIAS(fwrite);
                                                                                          ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:259:43: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      printf(const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(1, 2);
                                              ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:266:42: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      scanf(const char * __restrict, ...) __scanflike(1, 2);
                                             ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:269:63: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      sprintf(char * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(2, 3) __swift_unavailable("U...
                                                                  ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:270:68: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      sscanf(const char * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __scanflike(2, 3);
                                                                       ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:273:21: error: expected parameter declarator
__swift_unavailable("Use mkstemp(3) instead.")
                    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:273:21: error: expected ')'
/usr/include/stdio.h:273:20: note: to match this '('
__swift_unavailable("Use mkstemp(3) instead.")
                   ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:275:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
__deprecated_msg("This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inher...
^
/usr/include/stdio.h:279:68: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      vfprintf(FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict, va_list) __printflike(2, 0);
                                                                       ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:280:48: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      vprintf(const char * __restrict, va_list) __printflike(1, 0);
                                                   ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:281:68: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      vsprintf(char * __restrict, const char * __restrict, va_list) __printflike(2, 0) __swift_unavailab...
                                                                       ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:461:65: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      asprintf(char ** __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(2, 3);
                                                                    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:468:70: error: expected function body after function declarator
int      vasprintf(char ** __restrict, const char * __restrict, va_list) __printflike(2, 0);
                                                                         ^
tset.c:4:4: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("OK");
   ^
tset.c:4:4: note: include the header <stdio.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'printf'
1 warning and 18 errors generated.
```

and i delete the  #include   in the test.c

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World");
  return 0;
}
```

and run again terminnal shows:

```
Hello World
```

Just wonder ....why

Comment: `gcc` or `clang`?

Comment: i used gcc to compile, now i figure out the problem, just use 

    brew install libsvm

Comment: no .. but i still cant  compile any c code

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my MACOS have something wrong, I figure out that I changed some .cpp or .h file in my /usr/local/.. so I just reset the whole system hahahah. What a sad story